# video takes long time in loading in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, iostream

I am trying to play a video from a server using MPMoviePlayerController and NSURL.  The video plays perfectly but it takes lot of time in loading. Following is my code:

```
- (void) readyPlayer {
    mp =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    if ([mp respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) {
        // Set movie player layout
        [mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
        [mp setFullscreen:YES];

        // May help to reduce latency
        [mp prepareToPlay];

        // Register that the load state changed (movie is ready)
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self           
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
    }

    else{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:nil];
}



- (void) moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [lblActivity removeFromSuperview];
    [activity stopAnimating];
    // Unless state is unknown, start playback
    if ([mp loadState] != MPMovieLoadStateUnknown)
    {
        // Remove observer        
        [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] 
         removeObserver:self
         name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
         object:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];

        // Rotate the view for landscape playback      
        [[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
        [[self view] setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
        [[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)]; 

        // Set frame of movieplayer
        [[mp view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];

        // Add movie player as subview
        [[self view] addSubview:[mp view]];   

        // Play the movie
        [mp play];
    }
}
```

Can some one help me figuring out why it is taking so much time in loading?

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming its obviously not a problem with your internet connection on the phone. Did you try loading the same video on your phone, from your app and another native app (say YouTube or Safari) to see if there is a difference?

Looking at a similar code we've done, I'm wondering about the need of explicitly calling the `[mp prepareToPlay];` method. Its automatically called when `play` is called, so we haven't explicitly done so. Could you try it out without this method to see if there is a difference?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Madhumal, Thanks for replying I have followed your suggestion and removed [mp prepareToPlay] line. But it still took close to 28 seconds in playing video. My internet connection is fine and it usually does not take so much time in playing a streamed video.

Comment: Hi pankaj, just to test it under similar conditions, did you try loading the same URL from Safari on the same phone (not on your desktop browser or anything)? If this results in a noticeably faster load time, then it'll be safe to assume this is probably an issue with your app.

Comment: 28seconds is by far exceeding what a regular app / stream takes. Usually we are talking 3-10seconds.